# ruby on rails includes not working to get data for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have created two models having definition below

```
class TrendGraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_many :trends
end


class Trend < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
end
```

Now i am trying to pull the data for every graph along with the related trends data. i am using the below query

```
@trendGraphs =    TrendGraph.where("column=?",@someValue).all.includes(:trends)
```

but all i am getting in @trendGraphs is the trend graph table data and not the related data from trends table. What i need is something like below

```
TrendGraphData1:{key1:"value1",key2:"value2",trends:[{trendk1:"trendvalue1"},{trendk2:"trendvalue2"}]}
```

i was able to achieve this using the with clause in laravel and just shifted from laravel to ROR . Can one please help me telling what i am doing wrong and how it can be achieved ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can access you graph using @trendGraph.trends, working with item of trendGraph collection, but if you want another representation of this data, probably you need to find other ORM pattern like DAO, or you some kind of serializers. Because AR, as some people say is anti-patter, so query to it will return only rows of this model's table

Comment: i can access them using @trendGraphs.trends , but is there a way i can get all the related data in trends table as collection embedded with in the TrendGraph AR object ? or as you said i will need to use some ORM pattern to achieve this ?

Comment: You can make a json object like @trendGraph.to_json(include: :trends). But for composite AR object you need to use sth else

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
belongs_to :trend_graph
```

in your `Trend` class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
@trend_graphs = TrendGraph.where(column: @someValue).all.includes(:trends).as_json(include: :trends)
```

Comment: is there a way i can use (include: :trends) without using as_json ? i am just gathering the collections and in the last i am sending them using :json method to the view !